# Moving project from No Organization to an existing Organization in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform

After renaming a project, GCP automatically moved it under `No Organization`, which is not what I intended. Now I want to move the project back to the existing organization, but can't set the permissions in `No Organization` to make the migration. Any ideas on how to resolve this?

Comment: Renaming a project doesn't change the attached organization. However, you can change the organization of a project by following that doc https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/project-migration

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Thanks for the reply. In my case, renaming the project did change the attached organization for some reason. Now under the new organization (e.g No Organization), I don't have the permissions to migrate the project back to the original organization

Comment: If the organization change, you did something unusual. I repeat, change the project name don't change the organization, especially because you change only the display name of the project, not the project ID or the project Number, and those values are still attached to the organization. Maybe you use a third party tool, like terraform or something like that, but not the rename project of the UI.

Comment: Also, what permissions do you have in the problem project? Your question needs history and details on the problem,.

Comment: @JohnHanley I am the owner of the problem project, but I cannot set permissions in the problem organization...

Comment: Review the audit logs at the time you renamed the project to discover what actually happened. I rename projects all the time, nothing happens to ORG level ownership. I would also double-check the billing account assigned to the project. I would get together with an ORG Administrator and work together to reattach the project and ensure billing is correct.

Comment: Have you tried this docs regarding [Migrating projects with no organization](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/project-migration#migrating_projects_no_org)? Since you're the owner of the project you can set the required [permissions](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/project-migration#assign_permissions) before moving the poject. For the full guide you may refer in [here](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/project-migration).